# Puppeteer `waitForNavigation` always return timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

This question might have been asked previously but all the existing solutions in Stackoverflow were not able to help me. I have the following snippet:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const loginFn = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const deviceWidth = 1920;
  const deviceHeight = 1080;

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
  await page.setViewport({ width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight });
  await page.setUserAgent(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
  );
  await page.goto('https://testwebsite.com/');

  await page.click('.qrNYy');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]');

  await page.type('input[type="email"]', 'test@gmail.com');
  await page.type('input[type="password"]', 'test123');

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('.ffwHVz'),
    page.waitForNavigation({
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    }),
  ]);

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
  await browser.close();
}

(async () => {
  await loginFn();
})();
```

I always get `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded` error, I tried all options for `waitUntil` including `networkidle0`, `networkidle2`, `load` and `domcontentloaded` to no avail (these came from googling and stackoverflow). I also used `Promise.all` on `click` and `waitForNavigation` as suggested by many of those aforementioned solutions but I can't seem to bypass this issue.

Is it because of the website itself? Is this a case to case basis depending on the website itself or is it my code? Note: testwebsite.com is just a sample but that's what exactly happens on the site I'm testing on, I can't seem to get thru no matter how hard I try. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Which site are you actually scraping? Code seems OK on a glance but I can't really run this to say much more.

Comment: @ggorlen https://coinmarketcap.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer doc for [waitForNavigation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) states:

> This resolves when the page navigates to a new URL or reloads

Being an SPA, Coinmarketcap doesn't reload page or navigate to another page when logging in or registering, so `waitForNavigation` won't work here.

Instead I suggest that you wait for an element which is only present when a user is logged in. This will probably work (untested):

```
  await Promise.all([
    page.click('.ffwHVz'),
    page.waitForSelector('.icon-User-Filled'),
  ]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't always good enough because some sites will have the same page structure (markup) and the only thing that might change is the data. The only solution I have so far is waiting for an arbitrary number of seconds.

Comment: @andromeda That is not the only solution. You can also monitor data changes and react accordingly. Waiting for a number of seconds is one of the solutions of course, but very unreliable one.